# Passing string between viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c

I want to pass a string from one viewcontroller to another using properties (approach). Can anyone explain me in detail using objective c? Should we use storyboard in properties(approach)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this on how to ask a proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please have a look at this link, which explains how to ask a proper question, unfortunately you are too broad: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .
Plus I've tried searching on Google with the title you used: the first page contains only similar question from StackOverflow.
Probably you can already find what you need, in case you have still problem we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard segues and want to pass stringA to stringB on another ViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourVCIdentifier"])
    {
        YourViewController *yourVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        yourVC.stringB = stringA;
}
```

If not:

```
YourViewController *yourVC = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
yourVC.stringB = stringA;
[self presentViewController: yourVC animated:true completion:nil];
```